# Unable to start mongodb server. I am getting error as below :48

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
[
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.276+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "NETWORK",
    "id": 4915701,
    "ctx": "-",
    "msg": "Initialized wire specification",
    "attr": {
      "spec": {
        "incomingExternalClient": {
          "minWireVersion": 0,
          "maxWireVersion": 13
        },
        "incomingInternalClient": {
          "minWireVersion": 0,
          "maxWireVersion": 13
        },
        "outgoing": {
          "minWireVersion": 0,
          "maxWireVersion": 13
        },
        "isInternalClient": true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.279+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "CONTROL",
    "id": 23285,
    "ctx": "main",
    "msg": "Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.279+07:00"
    },
    "s": "W",
    "c": "ASIO",
    "id": 22601,
    "ctx": "main",
    "msg": "No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.279+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "NETWORK",
    "id": 4648602,
    "ctx": "main",
    "msg": "Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.282+07:00"
    },
    "s": "W",
    "c": "ASIO",
    "id": 22601,
    "ctx": "main",
    "msg": "No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.284+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "REPL",
    "id": 5123008,
    "ctx": "main",
    "msg": "Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService",
    "attr": {
      "service": "TenantMigrationDonorService",
      "ns": "config.tenantMigrationDonors"
    }
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.284+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "REPL",
    "id": 5123008,
    "ctx": "main",
    "msg": "Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService",
    "attr": {
      "service": "TenantMigrationRecipientService",
      "ns": "config.tenantMigrationRecipients"
    }
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.284+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "CONTROL",
    "id": 5945603,
    "ctx": "main",
    "msg": "Multi threading initialized"
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.284+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "CONTROL",
    "id": 4615611,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "MongoDB starting",
    "attr": {
      "pid": 40244,
      "port": 27017,
      "dbPath": "/data/db",
      "architecture": "64-bit",
      "host": "macs-MacBook-Pro.local"
    }
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.284+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "CONTROL",
    "id": 23403,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "Build Info",
    "attr": {
      "buildInfo": {
        "version": "5.0.6",
        "gitVersion": "212a8dbb47f07427dae194a9c75baec1d81d9259",
        "modules": [],
        "allocator": "system",
        "environment": {
          "distarch": "x86_64",
          "target_arch": "x86_64"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.284+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "CONTROL",
    "id": 51765,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "Operating System",
    "attr": {
      "os": {
        "name": "Mac OS X",
        "version": "18.7.0"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.284+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "CONTROL",
    "id": 21951,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "Options set by command line",
    "attr": {
      "options": {
        "net": {
          "port": 27017
        },
        "storage": {
          "dbPath": "/data/db"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.286+07:00"
    },
    "s": "E",
    "c": "CONTROL",
    "id": 20568,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "Error setting up listener",
    "attr": {
      "error": {
        "code": 9001,
        "codeName": "SocketException",
        "errmsg": "Address already in use"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.287+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "REPL",
    "id": 4784900,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown",
    "attr": {
      "waitTimeMillis": 15000
    }
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.287+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "COMMAND",
    "id": 4784901,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.287+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "SHARDING",
    "id": 4784902,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.287+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "NETWORK",
    "id": 4784905,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "Shutting down the global connection pool"
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.287+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "NETWORK",
    "id": 4784918,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.287+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "SHARDING",
    "id": 4784921,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.287+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "ASIO",
    "id": 22582,
    "ctx": "MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor",
    "msg": "Killing all outstanding egress activity."
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.287+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "COMMAND",
    "id": 4784923,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.287+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "CONTROL",
    "id": 4784925,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "Shutting down free monitoring"
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.287+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "CONTROL",
    "id": 4784927,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "Shutting down the HealthLog"
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.287+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "CONTROL",
    "id": 4784928,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "Shutting down the TTL monitor"
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.287+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "CONTROL",
    "id": 4784929,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.287+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "-",
    "id": 4784931,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.287+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "FTDC",
    "id": 4784926,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "Shutting down full-time data capture"
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.287+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "CONTROL",
    "id": 20565,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "Now exiting"
  },
  {
    "t": {
      "$date": "2022-03-11T17:51:24.287+07:00"
    },
    "s": "I",
    "c": "CONTROL",
    "id": 23138,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "Shutting down",
    "attr": {
      "exitCode": 48
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: According `"errmsg": "Address already in use"` it looks like you try to start MongoDB twice, i.e. it is already running.